# How to avoid text overlapping in pie chart with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  clase = c("Insecta", "Arachnida", "Entognatha", "Chilopoda", "Malacostraca"),
  n = c(245L, 30L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
  percent = c(
    87.5, 10.71428571428571352442, 1.071428571428571396851,
    0.3571428571428571507873, 0.3571428571428571507873
  ),
)


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n, fill = clase)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.65, label = round(percent, 1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 7) +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  coord_polar("y")
```

output (undesired text overlapping)

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: `ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(x = 1.6, label = round(percent, 1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 7) +` plus it has some additional parameters to adjust the padding.